# Is LESS ready for use in a production site?

Tags: css

I'm considering using the Twitter Bootstrap HTML/CSS templates which use [Less](http://lesscss.org/) (a sort of scripting language for CSS)

I've never used it so I was wondering if it's ready for "prime time".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the Twitter website has quite a few hits each day, so if it's good enough for them then I think it's ready for "prime time".

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure exactly where you think any problems might be, but LESS itself isn't supported by browsers. The LESS code you write is compiled into regular CSS, so the "support" is the same as CSS.

If you use LESS on the client-side with Javascript, then support is great (i.e. including IE6+). You can also use it on the server-side which resolves any potential problems with non-Javascript users.

Furthermore, you don't even need to use LESS, you can use vanilla CSS instead.